# ReportLab Breakline is not working ( big text )

Tags: python, oracle, reportlab

I know about `<br />` but it's not working for me...

I have a single long line so I had to use textwrap to wrap it into smaller lines

example: `separate_text = ('<br/>'.join(textwrap.wrap(text, 64)))`

1 - I got a big text from a database ( over than 300 characters )

2 - I need to insert this text in a pdf without go over the border on the right

Here's my code and my attempt to break a line

```
query = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM Queries WHERE id_query = '"+id_query+"'").fetchall()

listed_queries = []
     for i in query:
         listed_queries.append(i)

real_listed_queries = list(listed_queries[0])

txt = real_listed_queries[5]

t = ('<br/>'.join(textwrap.wrap(txt, 64)))

c.drawString(50, 355, t)
```

And my failed result is:

[printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTn0W.png)

Comment: `<br />` is for HTML and I'm not sure if `ReportLab` can convert it. Maybe you will have to run for-loop and every line display with `c.drawString()`

Comment: it seems `<br/>` works with `Paragraph()` which need `SimpleDocTemplate()`

Comment: it seems `Paragraph()` with `SimpleDocTemplate()` can wrap text automatically even without `<br/>` or `\n`